# NSURLSession thread changes in macOS 10.12?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, multithreading

I have had this code working for about 12 months and just tried to make some unrelated changes today, building using Xcode 9 for the first time with this macOS application. The code works when called from within the main view controller init, but fails every other time with a timeout. However, the server never logs the second and subsequent calls. I have checked that the last Xcode 8 build is still working, so I assume it is some change to threading?

```
+ (void) postRequest:(NSString *)url withContentType:(NSString *)contentType body:(NSData *)body onCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSDictionary *json, NSError *error))onCompletion
{
    NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    postRequest.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    [postRequest addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    postRequest.HTTPBody = body;
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:postRequest completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSDictionary *json = ( data != nil ) ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil] : [NSDictionary dictionary];
        BOOL success = !error && ![[json valueForKey:ERROR] integerValue];
        onCompletion( success, json, error);
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

I think the operations are deliberately placed on background threads, but I am at a loss as to how to take this forward. Putting it on the main thread at different points has no effect.

I don't know if it is related, but I use a custom NSURLProtocol to insert an authorisation header and another difference is that the protocol is being called multiple times for each call, when it used to be called just once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as replacing the line:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
```

with:

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config];
```